# Where can I find a list of the available extensions for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

Just wondering if there is an official list for extensions that are available for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a frequently asked question.

- Users and SQL calls them "extensions". You add them with `CREATE EXTENSION`.
- They get packaged by distros like Ubuntu as `postgresql-contrib` or the like.
- The docs calls them [*"Additional Supplied Modules"*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html), but *"modules"* isn't really used anywhere else.  I'm not sure you should ever call anything a module, but it seems to be used here to refer to packaged extensions. Perhaps it's from the days when extensions were just SQL scripts.

You can find the [list of PostgreSQL extensions officially supported here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html).

[PGXN.org](http://pgxn.org/) is a great resource for finding third party modules/extensions/contrib-ie stuff too.